# How can I send ethers from my smart contract to another address using transfer?

Tags: solidity, address.transfer, wallet-transfer, sendrawtransaction

`recievers_address.transfer(address(this).balance);`

when I use this from one of the functions of my smart contract

`Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.`

red underlined under the receivers-address!

to be noted: recievers_address is a private field.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, this is just a guess, but maybe you're using Solidity 0.5.x and `recievers_address` is declared as an `address` rather than an `address payable`?

Comment: exactly, do I need to make every `address` to `address payable` for being able to send ether using transfer?

Comment: Any address you send ether to should be `address payable`, yes.